# How can I determine where a logged error came from in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have this error in my laravel.log file:

```
[2022-01-25 23:28:26] production.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1478656 bytes) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1478656 bytes) at /home/site/public_html/software/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php:63)
[stacktrace]
```

However, there is no further stack trace. Most errors in my log have the full stack there and I can find the location of the error. With this one, there is nothing.

This is an Apache server running on Ubuntu.

Any way to find where this error came from?

Comment: Increase the memory limit? 32 MiB seems inadequately low.

Comment: There is no stack trace because it is a PHP memory limit error. The memory limit is indeed very low.

Comment: `at /home/site/public_html/software/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php:63)` Line 63

Comment: 32MB is not the memory limit setting I have on the server. I have no idea where this is coming from. If it was 32MB all my crons would fail and everything seems to be working correctly except for this mystery.

Comment: CRONS use the PHP CLI and there is no memory limit on the CLI

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh great, I guess I'll edit the PhpEngine file to fix the error. Thanks, that's of tremendous help

Comment: `memory_limit = 128M` for example in the `php.ini`